# Wrong matching output on igraph max_bipartite_match function?

Tags: r, igraph

I have trouble understanding the output of of the `max_bipartite_match` function, the output does not seems to correspond to a matching while it is clear form the output that the algorithm has actually found the maximal matching.

I tried to read the documentation but it did not help me :

Here is an example :

[Network](https://ibb.co/L0wFVMp)

and  the code :

```r
library(igraph)
bp <- make_bipartite_graph(types=c(rep(TRUE,3),rep(FALSE,3)),edges = c(1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 4,
                      3, 5, 3, 6), directed = FALSE)
set.seed(512)
E(bp)$weight <- runif(length(igraph::E(bp)), 0, 1)
plot(bp,layout=layout_as_bipartite(bp),edge.label=sprintf("%0.2f",E(bp)$weight))
max_bipartite_match(bp,eps=0.00001)
```

The output is :

```
$matching_size
[1] 3

$matching_weight
[1] 2.032942

$matching
[1] 6 4 5 2 3 1
```

However 6,4,5 are all in the same component, so matching does not represent an edge sequence. I tried some other interpretations (6-2 odes not exist nor 4-3) and I still don't understand the output.

To me the maximum matching as an edge sequence should be 2-4 5-3 2-6 and it is clear that the algorithm found it because the matching_weight is 2.03, which is coherent.

To me it even looks like a bug.

Does anybody have an explanation ?

Thanks,
Alexis

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so for future users :

Actually each elements of the matching correspond to an edge between the vertex corresponding to this position and the matching element at this position. In my example the matching corresponding to 6 4 5 2 3 1 is :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
| | | | | |
6 4 5 2 3 1
```

This is confusing because each edge is listed twice as my graph is undirected, but it is correct.

I tested this hypothesis on 1000 random graph and it worked every times.